# Can AWS SES send bounce/complaint objects to an http endpoint?

Tags: php, json, amazon-web-services

I've read through quite a lot of documentation already, and I'm still not clear or whether or not AWS is the right solution for our problem. The solution we need is:

- Send E-mails that are tracked for complaints & bounces
- Receive these bounces & complaints via an http endpoint (with information as to the e-mail address that was bounced, when and why)

I've seen that maybe something like this could be possible in connection with their SNS service, but the question remains open to me, whether these two services will actually work together to provide a detailed object with bounces/complaints to a url that I can then process & display as I wish.

Anyone had any experience or done something similar to what I would like to do, and what was your solution? Oh and my language of choice is PHP, if that helps.

Thanks.

Comment: Mandrill, mailgun, sendgrind are some of the services that offer what you need. I can't comment on AWS since I haven't had experience on it with emails yet.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Amazon SES can do what you are wanting to do.

You will use SES and SNS together. You can configure SES to publish complaints and bouncebacks to Amazon SNS topics. You can then subscribe an HTTP endpoint to these topics to receive notifications when complaints and bouncebacks occur. Here are some of the pages of the SES documentation that you are going to want to read:

- [Amazon SES Feedback Notifications via Amazon SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/notifications-via-sns.html)
- [Configuring Amazon SES Feedback Notifications via Amazon SNS](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-sns-notifications.html)
- [Processing Bounces and Complaints](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/best-practices-bounces-complaints.html)

For receiving the SNS messages in your PHP code, you can use the [AWS SDK for PHP](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php). The [Receiving Amazon SNS Messages in PHP](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/post/Tx2G9D94IE6KPAY/Receiving-Amazon-SNS-Messages-in-PHP) article on the [AWS PHP Development Blog](http://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/blog) describes how to use the SDK to do this.

To test, you can use the [SES Mailbox Simulator](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/mailbox-simulator.html), which just involves using your account to send emails to special email addresses provided by SES (e.g., bounce@simulator.amazonses.com).

Comment: I believe this page http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/SubscribeTopic.html can be helpful, too. This explains how you can subscribe to an endpoint, it could be a HTTP endpoint.

Comment: The AWS documentation here is pretty beefy but leaves no real solution. I wrote his a couple years back and should have shared it here sooner. https://trentmillar.github.io/amazon-ses-email/2016/12/23/amazon-ses-notifications-sent-to-httphttps-service-using-sns-and-nodejs The post is long but it covers what Peter asked.